# C. Input double.

Tags: c

I can't understand why it doesn't work. (It is necessary that X ^ 2> 1)

```
double input()
{
    double x;
    printf("x:");
    scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    if((x*x)<=1)
        input();
    else return x;  
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to 'return input()?

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? What do you think it should do and what do you observe it doing?

Comment: Besides, recursion is not really the best way of handling this requirement.

Comment: Probably yes, Martin. What`s better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the branch that calls `input` has no return statement. You can rewrite your code like this:

```
double input()
{
    double x;
    printf("x:");
    scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    if((x*x)<=1)
        return input();
    else
        return x;  
}
```

but using a loop instead of recursion makes your code more readable:

```
double input()
{
    double x;
    do {
        printf("x:");
        scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    } while (x*x<=1.0);
    return x;  
}
```